# CoreData: error: Serious application error. Exception was caught during Core Data change processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi I'm getting crash,

when i'm trying to insert 1000 records into db in back ground, i'm getting following exception:
`CoreData: error: Serious application error`.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.
This is usually a bug within an observer of

```
NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)2013-11-19 09:41:19.587 3pTalk[7487:907]

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
```

I used the code for inserting objexts

```
dispatch_queue_t myBackgroundQ = dispatch_queue_create("com.sample.addressbook", NULL);
// Could also get a global queue; in this case, don't release it below.
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delay, myBackgroundQ, ^(void){
    [self userAddressbook];
});
dispatch_release(myBackgroundQ);
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startSyncLoader) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: What does the code look like that does the actual insert.  It looks like you could be trying to add a nil object to a To-Many relationship or using a managedObjectContext on the wrong thread.

Comment: where is the code that inserts the data into the database?

Answer (score 16):

Dont access same Database(Persistent Store Coordinator) from 2 threads(Main,Background) simultaneously with one context. This is not recommended. it causes App Crash.

create NSManagedContext Object and set persistentstoreCoordinator.

```
    dispatch_queue_t request_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.xxx.ScsMethod", NULL);
    dispatch_async(request_queue, ^{
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *mainThreadContextStoreCoordinator = [context     persistentStoreCoordinator]; //
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]; // 
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:mainThreadContextStoreCoordinator];}
```

Comment: @NirMH create NSManagedContext Object and set persistentstoreCoordinator.  dispatch_queue_t request_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.xxx.ScsMethod", NULL);
        dispatch_async(request_queue, ^{  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *mainThreadContextStoreCoordinator = [context persistentStoreCoordinator];
//            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
//            [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:mainThreadContextStoreCoordinator];}

Answer (score 2):

Are you accessing the database from two threads simultaneously?, using same context? That may be the reason.  see this question

[Problems Adding to NSMutableArray: attempt to insert nil object at 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970868/problems-adding-to-nsmutablearray-attempt-to-insert-nil-object-at-10)