# Can't delete a record from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i have a table view where Im performing a deletion: (just the relevant methods)

```
#import "StackTableViewController.h"
#import "Target.h"
#import "StackTableViewCell.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@interface StackTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultController;

@end

@implementation StackTableViewController

- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"StackTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
        [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
        Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.currentTarget = current.body;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

    Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.currentTarget = current.body;

}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

// just to ignor a warning
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.fetchedResultController.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}




- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    [[stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target];

    [stack saveContext];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StackTableViewCell";

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    StackTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.cellLabel.text = target.body;

    cell.cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:20];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


- (NSFetchRequest *)targetsFetchRequest {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Target"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return fetchRequest;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultController {

    if (_fetchedResultController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self targetsFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:stack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    _fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultController;

}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        default:
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

and as you can see i created a delegate method for the table view controller to tell the home view controller that a deletion was made, so I can update some table in the home view controller.

HomeViewController.h: (just the relevant methods)

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "CreateViewController.h"
#import "ProfileViewController.h"
#import "StackTableViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController () <StackTableViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *homeLabel;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
        stackTableViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];
        stackTableViewController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.homeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:40];

    self.homeLabel.text = stackTableViewController.currentTarget;
}


- (void)didDeleteObject {

    self.homeLabel.text = stackTableViewController.currentTarget;
}
```

but now not only that the label is not getting updated whenever the first cell was deleted, I can't perform the deletion....it seems to crash at the saveContext call...

this is the error i'm getting:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:]: range {0, 4} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 2] with userInfo (null)
2014-12-21 15:35:18.392 Treats[4153:582136] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:]: range {0, 4} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

this is my CoreDataStack class (singleton):

```
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@implementation CoreDataStack

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

+ (instancetype)defaultStack {

    static CoreDataStack *defaultStack;
    static dispatch_once_t onceTocken;
    dispatch_once (&onceTocken, ^{
        defaultStack = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return defaultStack;
}


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "digitalCrown.Treats" in the application's documents directory.
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Treats" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Treats.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}


@end
```

please help :/

tnx

Comment: What does the stack look like when you crash?  Also, any message in the debug console?

Comment: hey, i added the error buddy..the stack is ok i think, its not nil or something @PhillipMills

Comment: I want that if I delete the first cell in the table view my homeLabel will be updated, this is my goal here @PhillipMills

Comment: According to the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20063340/2274694 this can be caused by accessing the Persistent Store Coordinator from two threads simultaneously. When are you reloading your table data?

Comment: in the `init` method and in the `viewDidLoad` method (both in stacktableviewcontroller) it looks like this: `        [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];` @LyndseyScott

Comment: But your *table* data... Are you reloading your table anywhere?

Comment: i think I don't have the reloadData method since i'm working with fetchedresultcontroller, in the tutorial i followed I didn't need to use it :/ @LyndseyScott

Comment: I'm not asking about whether or not your using that method... Just asking if your table is reloading. Because if you're changing your managed object on one thread while accessing it on another, like I said, you can run into issues. I'm just trying to figure out where else your managed object is being accessed and it sounds as if you may be simultaneously accessing that data in your cellForRowAtIndexPath. But if you'd like to post a link to that tutorial, I could take a quick look to confirm.

Comment: I added the core data stack class where I manage the core data @LyndseyScott

Comment: That doesn't answer my question for you at all...

Comment: @LyndseyScott now I shared the whole TableViewClass you can look at the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you received can be caused by accessing the Persistent Store Coordinator from two threads simultaneously.

As we've figured out throughout the comment thread, in this particular case, the error was caused because the core data fetch was performed in two places simultaneously upon the view controller's creation by having this line

```
[self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
```

in both the `init` and `viewDidLoad` methods. So to solve this problem, only call `performFetch` in either `init` or `viewDidLoad` -- not both.

Comment: I need to declare request_queue somewhere..?

Comment: @JohnBigs Oh shoot, sorry... Copied and pasted bad code.  One sec.

Comment: still same error...oreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:]: range {0, 4} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 2] with userInfo (null)

Comment: @JohnBigs OK, I'll edit my answer to the first version I had up here, so you can try that too.

Comment: @JohnBigs Just rolled back my answer, but commented out the `saveContext` line for now just because it could potentially cause an issue if I'm misunderstanding the docs and `didChangeObject:` is also called upon `saveContext`. When you edit the code to what I have above, do you still get the error?

Comment: @JohnBigs Hm... Somewhere your Persistent Store Coordinator is being accessed from another thread... Have to track that down...

Comment: thanks for the help, gave you a like on your fb page ;)

Comment: @JohnBigs Question: When `[_delegate didDeleteObject];` does it do anything other than update the label?

Comment: is it ok that in the HomeViewController I imported the StackTableViewController this way : #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StackTableViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
    
    StackTableViewController *stackTableViewController;
}  ?

Comment: @JohnBigs That's fine, but you haven't initialized stackTableViewController properly. You need to refer to the current instance, not create a new one.

Comment: i did: stackTableViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc] init];
in my HomeViewController...

Comment: @JohnBigs Yeah, that's creating a *new* instance. Not using the current one.

Comment: oh shot, so how should I'v write this? sorry i'm newbie :/

Comment: ...? is that my problem? @Lyndsey Scott

Comment: the problem is that I can't perform fetch for the fetchresultcontroller in the init and in the view did load...if I delete one of them it works

Comment: @JohnBigs So that's where your Persistent Store Coordinator is being accessed from two threads at the same time... That makes sense. I'll update my answer to explain the source for future answer seekers.

Comment: @JohnBigs Actually my answer would have to be super re-edited to explain. I think you should write out your own answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: but I don't know how to explain it as you do :), I got the idea to check it from you...I can Only say that you can't perform fetch from init and viewDidLoad together, I actually asked another question about it few minutes ago to understand it

Comment: @JohnBigs Updated. Look OK to you?

Comment: funny thing, I could add the perform fetch to view did load too just after I set my fetchedResultsController to nil...